# Counting lists of length $100$ from the set $\{0,1,2\}$ such that the total is $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $b_n$ be the number of lists of length $100$ from the set $\{0,1,2\}$ such that the sum of their entries is $n$. How does $b_{198}$ equal ${100\choose 2}+100$?

Comment: Isn't $b_n$ the number of lists of length 100 from {0,1,2} with sum n?

Comment: The number $198$ is pretty special. In order to get it, you must have $98$ $2$'s and two $1$'s or $99$ $2$'s and one $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$b_{198}$ calculation:

99 twos and a zero - $100$

98 twos and 2 ones - $^{100}C_2$

Comment: why does 100C2?

Comment: With 98 twos and 2 ones, there are 100-choose-2 possibilities for ordering (i.e., two select positions in the list for the two ones, and fill the rest of the 98 with twos)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
b_{n} &=\sum_{n_{0}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{1}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{2}=0}^{\infty}
\delta_{n_{0}\ +\ n_{1}\ +\ n_{2},100}\,
\delta_{0\,\times\,n0\ +\ 1\,\times\,n_{1}\ +\ 2\,\times\,n_{2},n}\tag{1}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n_{0}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{1}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{2}=0}^{\infty}
\int_{\verts{z}=1}{1 \over z^{-n_{0} - n_{1} - n_{2} + 101}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}
\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{1 \over z'^{-n_{1} - 2n_{2} + n + 1}}\,{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}
\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z^{101}}
\,{1 \over z'^{n + 1}}\,\pars{\sum_{n_{0} = 0}^{\infty}z^{n_{0}}}
\bracks{\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\pars{zz'}^{n_{1}}}
\bracks{\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\pars{zz'^{2}}^{n_{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}
\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z^{101}}\,{1 \over z'^{n + 1}}\,
{1 \over 1 - z}\,{1 \over 1 - zz'}\,{1 \over 1 - zz'^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z^{101}}\,{1 \over 1 - z}
\color{#f00}{\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z'^{n + 1}}\,
{1 \over 1 - zz'}\,{1 \over 1 - zz'^{2}}}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#f00}{\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z'^{n + 1}}\,
> {1 \over 1 - zz'}\,{1 \over 1 - zz'^{2}}}
> =\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z'^{n + 1}}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{zz'}^{\ell}
> \sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}\pars{zz'^{2}}^{\ell'}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell'}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
> \int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{z'^{\ell + 2\ell'} \over z'^{n + 1}}
> =\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell'}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
> \delta_{\ell,n - 2\ell'}
> =\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{N}z^{n - \ell'}
> \\&\mbox{where}\ N \equiv \floor{n \over 2}
> \end{align}
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#f00}{\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z'^{n + 1}}\,
> {1 \over 1 - zz'}\,{1 \over 1 - zz'^{2}}}
> =z^{n}\,{\pars{1/z}^{N + 1} - 1 \over 1/z - 1}
> =\color{#f00}{z^{n - N}\,{1 - z^{N + 1} \over 1 - z}}
> \end{align}

Now, we replace this result in expression $\pars{2}$:
\begin{align}
b_{n}&=
\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z^{N - n + 101}}\,
{1 - z^{N + 1} \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}}
=\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over z^{N - n + 101}}\,
\pars{1 - z^{N + 1}}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}\ell z^{\ell - 1}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}\ell\pars{%
\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}\,{z^{\ell - 1} \over z^{N - n + 101}}
-
\int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}\,{z^{\ell} \over z^{-n + 101}}}
=\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}\ell\pars{%
\delta_{\ell,N - n + 101} - \delta_{\ell,-n + 100}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large b_{n}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large\pars{\floor{n \over 2} - n + 101}
> _{n - \floor{n \over 2}\ \leq\ 100}\ -\ \pars{100 - n}_{n\ \leq\ 99}}
> $$
>   ${\tt\mbox{When the condition at the right of}\ \pars{~~}\mbox{'s is false the}\ \pars{~~}\mbox{'s evaluates to}\ 0}$.

For example, when $n = 198$ we have that $198 - \floor{99} = 99 \leq 100$ is true but
$198 \leq 99$ is false. Then,
$$
b_{198} =\pars{\floor{198 \over 2} - 198 + 101} = {\large 2}
$$

The maximum value $\pars{~= 51~}$ occurs at $n = 100$. $b_{n}$ is symmetrical around $n = 100$ $\pars{~b_{n} = b_{200 - n}\,,\quad n \leq 100~}$ and vanishes out for $n > 200$. That means:
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
b_{n} =
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{lcc}
1 + \floor{n \over 2} & \mbox{if} & n \leq 99
\\[2mm]
51 & \mbox{if} & n = 100
\\[2mm]
b_{200 - n} & \mbox{if} & 101 \leq n \leq 200
\\[2mm]
0 && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}\tag{3}
$$
$\tt\mbox{Result}\ \pars{3}\ \mbox{is valid whenever we don't take into account the list order !!!}$.

> $\large\tt\mbox{ADDENDUM: Hereafter we take into account the list order}$
>   In this case, each factor in $\pars{1}$ is multiplied by $100!/\pars{n_{0}!\,n_{1}!\,n_{2}!}$ such that $\pars{2}$ is reduced to:
>   \begin{align}
> b_{n}&=
> 100!\int_{\verts{z'}=1}{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}\,{1 \over  z'^{n + 1}}
> \int_{\verts{z}=1}{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}\,
> {\expo{z\pars{1 + z' + z'^{2}}} \over z^{101}}
> =\int_{\verts{z'}=1}
> {\pars{1 + z' + z'^{2}}^{100} \over  z'^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z' \over 2\pi \ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z}=1}{1 \over  z^{n + 1}}
> \sum_{n_{0} =0, n_{1} = 0, n_{2} = 0 \atop n_{0} + n_{1} + n_{2} = 100}
> {100! \over n_{0}!\,n_{1}!\,n_{2}!}\,1^{n_{0}}z^{n_{1}}\pars{z^{2}}^{n_{2}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi \ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.\sum_{n_{0} =0, n_{1} = 0, n_{2} = 0}{100! \over n_{0}!\,n_{1}!\,n_{2}!}
> \right\vert_{n_{0}\ +\ n_{1}\ +\ n_{2}\ =\ 100
> \atop {\vphantom{\huge A}n_{1}\ +\ 2n_{2}\ =\ n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.\sum_{n_{0} = 100 - n}^{100 - \floor{n/2}}
> {100! \over n_{0}!\pars{200 - n - 2n_{0}}!\pars{n_{0} + n - 100}!}
> \right\vert_{n_{0}\ \geq\ 0}
> \end{align}

Indeed,
$$
b_{198}=\sum_{n_{0} = 0}^{1}{100! \over n_{0}!\pars{2 - 2n_{0}}!\pars{n_{0} + 98}!}
= {100! \over 2!\,98!} + 100 = \color{#00f}{{100 \choose 2} + 100} = 5050
$$

Comment: This is just wrong, since it ignores the order in a list. In particular the final formulas give $b_{198}=b_2=2$, which is not equal to $\binom{100}2+100$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You are right. With this method it's quite cumbersome to take that fact into account. I saw that feature because I did some manual essays. Any way, that is the answer when we ignore the order. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Also, I read $\tt\mbox{@Aneesh Karthik C}$ answer before I did the calculation. I will think further about that. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I just add and ADDENDUM which takes care of your initial comment. I guess there is a sort of reduction for the last general $b_{n}$ formula but I couldn't found that. Albeit this procedure is quite long it's very general and it can be used in many situations. Thanks.